# using mercurial sub repos with the same starting namespace

Tags: mercurial

let's say I have two projects

a) **com.foo.bar**

I have a folder structure of

```
com/foo/bar
```

b) **com.foo.morebar**

with a folder structure of

```
com/foo/morebar
```

Is it possible to add (b) as a sub repo of (a) at the top level ?

I have tried to do

```
echo com/foo/morebar = com/foo/morebar > .hgsub
hg add .hgsub
hg clone http://myurl/moreBarRepo com/foo/morebar
```

this, unfortunately (and quite obviously) creates a directory structure of

```
com/foo/morebar/com/foo/morebar
```

is there anyway of getting

```
com/foo/bar
```

and

```
com/foo/morebar
```

to exist using sub repos ?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You **can't** use **folder in repository** as subrepo in another repository. Period

In order to have `morebar` as subrepository of `bar` with path `com/foo/morebar` you must

1. [Convert](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/subrepositories/#converting-folder-into-a-subrepository) `morebar` into repository
2. Add `morebar` as subrepository into both wrapper-repos (`bar` and `morebar`), using **correct** RHS in `.hgsub` (read carefully and understand "Note" from [Subrepository topic](http://mercurial.aragost.com/kick-start/en/subrepositories/#id2) at Aragost Trifork's Mercurial Kick Start Exercises)